# How to loop form values depending on form column name?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form containing 6 check_num fields, 1 account number and an amount. I would like to insert those values into a database table:

```
<cfquery datasource="test" name="test">
    insert into test (ACCOUNT_NUMBER,check_num,amount)
    values ('#ACCOUNT_NUMBER#','#check_num#','#amount#')
</cfquery>
```

However, I don't want to insert all of the values into 1 row. If any of the check_num fields contain a number, I want to insert that value, along with with the acccount_number and amount values.

For example with the data below, I would like to insert 5 rows. The field "check_num6" would be skipped because it is empty.

```
ACCOUNT_NUMBER  123456789
CHECK_NUM1  56623
CHECK_NUM2  5512
CHECK_NUM3  6562
CHECK_NUM4  653
CHECK_NUM5  6623
CHECK_NUM6  
AMOUNT  32.31
FIELDNAMES  ACCOUNT_NUMBER,CHECK_NUM1,CHECK_NUM2,CHECK_NUM3,CHECK_NUM4,CHECK_NUM5,CHECK_NUM6,AMOUNT,SUBMIT
SUBMIT  Submit
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, not being sarcastic but did you [search the archives](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[coldfusion]+dynamic+form), because the question of handling dynamic form fields comes up *a lot* :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not perfect but you can start/get some inspiration from here:

```
<cfloop list="#StructKeyList(form)#" index="i">
    <cfif (left('#i#', 9) is "CHECK_NUM") and (trim(form['#i#']) is not "")>
        <cfquery datasource="test" name="test">
            insert into test (ACCOUNT_NUMBER,check_num,amount)
            values ('#ACCOUNT_NUMBER#','#form['#i#']#','#amount#')
        </cfquery>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Also you should validate, see if your DB supports multiple inserts, change your query to use cfqueryparam, research about it. So, a better cfquery code would be:

```
<cfquery datasource="test" name="test">
    insert into test (
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        check_num,
        amount
    )
    values (
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.ACCOUNT_NUMBER#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form['#i#']#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.amount#">
    )
</cfquery>
```

Comment: 1) Do not forget to scope all variables 2) Get rid of the extraneous `#` signs 3) Variable names like "fieldName" are more intuitive than "i". 4) In case they are not familiar with cfqueryparam, it would be good to include that in the example to demonstrate proper usage. (Though honestly I was just going to vote to close this as a duplicate, since the question has been been asked and answered ... many times ;-)

Comment: @Leigh, I'm with you, the code works but needs research and work, that is how you learn.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind people also learn from what we show them. Chances are this post will be read by many others in the future, some of whom may not (yet) know or understand what could be improved and why. The best way to encourage good practices in others, is to *demonstrate* them in our answers (especially with small code snippets) :-)

Comment: Also, 1) You can use a single query like `... VALUES (), (),...`
2) Use `len()` rather than `IS NOT ""`.

Comment: @Beginner, true, with that the decision becomes: <cfif (left('#i#', 9) is "CHECK_NUM") and len(trim(form['#i#']))>